# Appium Parallel Test Execution removes driver for one device, showing A session is either terminated or not started

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, testng, appium

Hi I tried to implement parallel test execution using TestNG and Appium, I used ThreadLocal. The problem is that one device after the first run is lost. But the other device is completed all its test.

Here is my code,

[BaseDriver](https://gist.github.com/ikhaled28/d3e364eda32e8de858fa394700a728d7)

[TestClass](https://gist.github.com/ikhaled28/c6bfcfc80bc689ddbe5a4c03c67a74db)

[TestListener](https://gist.github.com/ikhaled28/60cfb8fc0a0535653dbb4aeec6e5fc0d)

[TestNG XML](https://gist.github.com/ikhaled28/a45cc90a45a623b7bded8ea62a43cf13)

[Error Description](https://gist.github.com/ikhaled28/78bd2bfbd680e3c2044e4784b6f68ed8)

[Appium Server Log](https://gist.github.com/ikhaled28/3c28b70583890b5b381df3396b34c36a)

[Execution Log](https://gist.github.com/ikhaled28/4105c3356de9d12c4e063e7f7584e744)

I am struggling to find where the driver is removed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I added the appium server log also.

Comment: Can you provide entire execution log? especially where it logs thread details during creating and tearing down driver.  Any reason for not using available open source frameworks, for example [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/)? There are many proven oss frameworks available to avoid such common issues.

Comment: Hi I updated the Execution Log and we are trying to develop our own automation framework. Thats why we are not using any other open source frameworks right now.

Comment: You must use different appium driver and appium server for the device you want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by myself. As I am using System port and WDALocalPort I for single appium session, I don't need to use session override. Session overriding was replacing my current session's with a single new session. Anyway thanks everyone